Suggestions on how to keep drain tile in yard down?
In my yard, I have a section of drain tile connected to my gutter that's had the top exposed since I bought the house.  It was solidly in the ground, but probably 60-70% of what you see in the current picture was exposed. I dug it up and was able to dig under it about 2 inches until I hit some diagonally crossing irrigation lines.  However, the way the tile is bent, it wants to pop into the air.  I can stretch it away and push it down, but the tendency is for it to pop back up.  As you can see from the side picture, I need about the entire 2 inches to have an adequate layer of soil for the grass.
My first attempt was to bury the tile under some of the heavier clay I dug up, and then just reseeded over the top.  The ground was a little squishy like the tile was still moving a bit, but it seemed like it might work.  However, the next day we got an absolute downpour.  The intensity of the rain made it come shooting through the holes like a water fountain.  On top of that, there was water flowing down the driveway and it washed away most of the top soil.  Clearly this wasn't the fix.
For my second attempt, I purchased a section of 4 inch corrugated drain tile.  I'm going to cut a slit in it and then wrap it around the exist section with the slit facing down.  I also purchased some metal U shaped croquet wickets.  The plan is to pin the drain tile with the wickets.  My concern is that those wickets will still pull up when the ground is wet.
TL;DR How can I keep the drain tile "pinned down" and buried under the soil instead of popping up like it wants to do?
Solution That drain pipe was end-capped at the section I was working with, it wasn't connected to another pipe.  I cut a couple inches off of the pipe, pulled it tight, and end-capped it again.  I did use a couple of the wickets to keep things pinned down while I was working.  There was a hole in the endcap, so I surrounded that area with a couple inches of pea gravel.  Then I covered the pea gravel with top soil, and then just laid a piece of sod on top.  So far the sod is surviving and the entire setup survived a heavy rain Sunday night.  Thanks to everyone for their contributions.



What feeds into this drain pipe?  If it's only a single gutter, and as you said "The intensity of the rain made it come shooting through the holes like a water fountain.", I wonder if it's partially blocked?  Usually 4" pipe like that has plenty of capacity to handle a gutter, and so if it's shooting out, I wonder if you have a partially blocked line somewhere downstream of this point.

@Milwrdfan That's a fair consideration.  It's one gutter, although I do have a severely sloped roof.  Also I think the official measurement was like 1.3 inches of rain in about an hour.  At this point I'm planning on using a combination of answers.  I'm going to try and cut the one piece shorter and then tape it into the following piece and get the slack out of the line.  When I have it dug up, I can try shooting water down the following drain tile and see if it gets backed up.

It's corrugated drain hose. Calling it tile is a misleading misnomer. If you had actual clay drain tile, it would not do what this is doing. If you had rigid plastic drain pipe it would also be difficult (though slightly more likely than heavy clay pipe) for it to float out. This stuff is the worst available option for drainage use.

@Ecnerwal Thanks for the thoughts.  I clearly don't have much experience in this area.  Using the wrong terms is probably why I wasn't having much luck searching for solutions.  Unfortunately, it seems like this was a post build addition on all the gutters.  To be honest, I'm not even sure where these things flow out to.  Considering all that, I'm just trying to patch it up and keep it working, rather than really replacing or upgrading the entire system.  There's portion's of this that go under landscaping rocks.  Dealing with the entire thing would turn into a real project.

You'll probably need to expose one end and pull it tight.
This would involve digging up from where it's exposed all the way to one end (or the other), then pulling it tight so that you no longer have the slack that's allowing for the bulge. Once you've got it pulled tight, you can cover it back over. Note that it probably doesn't have to be tight, tight (i.e., not under a great amount of tension), but just pulling out the slack.
When you're digging, you can carefully cut the turf and roll it up or flap it over, dig below it and make the adjustments necessary, then fill the dirt back in and put the turf back down if you're concerned about the grass.
Without the slack, odds are good that you won't need to worry about pinning it down in any way, but you're free to do so. I'd doubt that something like a croquet wicket would do much to hold it down, but it might contribute until the soil has settled again.

It connects to another tile on both ends.  But the lower side of my dig area is by a connection point.  I did consider cutting the one end and kind of tucking it in to tighten the slack.  That could be an option if I can't come up with anything else.

It might not be necessary to dig up half of the pipe, you could possibly just cut a few inches out of the middle exposed section and re-join it. Simple enough since the pipe isn't watertight anyway, but you'll need to do some digging to have room to work.

Nuclear Hoagie replied at the same time lol.  I guess I'll have to look into re-joining tile like they mentioned.

Dig under, and to the side so that it has room to depress and flex outward.
